# customize title bar in chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to customize title bar in chrome packaged app?
I need to add some text and change the color of background.

I search something like this (which customizes scrollbar):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 15px;
background: #fcfcfc;
    }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #a5d0ff;
    -webkit-border-radius: .8ex;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there are any CSS selectors which target the application's title bar, but you don't have to use the system title bar at all in a Chrome app.

You can specify `frame: "none"` in the options object when you create your window -- that will completely remove the title bar, and you can add your own, using HTML and CSS for content and styling.

Demo app: [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/master/apps/samples/frameless-window)

Comment: how can I implement minimize then?

Comment: That's a different question :) If you post it, I can add an answer for that too. The short answer, though, is to call `minimize()` on your AppWindow object