# Hide Default title bar in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am creating a window on the launch app event, How can I be able to hide the default title bar so I can be able to create mine?

from [customize title bar in chrome packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330134/customize-title-bar-in-chrome-packaged-app), it was mentioned that we use `frame: none` but without showing how to implement it. How can I be able to implement it?

my `background.js`

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
      id: "main_window",
      'frame': none,
      'outerBounds': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 500
      },
      'innerBounds':{

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: `none` should be `"none"`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked